# How to interlink sibling websites?

Tags: website-design, metaphor

Backstory: I am building a non-profit website that will visualise public spending and there is a for-profit sibling that will generates revenue for the non-profit by selling the visualisation tool for a fee to private companies. They have similar websites except the non-profit is xxx.org and the for-profit is xxx.com.

**Is there an UI metaphor for interlinking related websites?** Maybe something like folded corner with a message "looking for xxx.org instead of xxx.com?"

Strangely I can not recall any example of interlinked sibling websites. For instance [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/) and [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/) are only linked by tiny link in the footer, I want something more prominent.

Answer (score 4):

StackExchange itself allows for a user to discover the total family or community of websites through a number of cross-pollination opportunities.

- Navbar / Masthead toggle: Make your users aware xxx exists within a larger context
- Sidebar: Related content from one site to another based on context.
- Content pages: Contextually provide opportunities to cross-promote. In your case, have a "powered by xxx visualization tool" in a footnote of the non-for-profit data/charts.

http://jquery.com/ does the same thing in the masthead of the site with subtle use of tabs.
[image]